# generalizing a recurrence

Tags: recurrence

I'm not sure how could I write code for the following recurrence:

`[a, b]    --> [a, a*2/3, a*1/3+b*2/3, b];`

`[a, b, c] --> [a, a*2/3, a*1/3+b*2/3, b, b*2/3+ c/3, b/3+c*2/3, c]`

that's it, takes a list, and expands that as in the example. I'm not sure how can I write code for that. Could someone please help me with that?

Comment: Did you make a typo?  Shouldn't the second term of the second list be `a*2/3+b/3`?  Also you probably shouldn't mix `a*1/3` and `a/3`, use one or the other throughout; they mean the same thing.

Comment: @CoryKendall You're right. Could you please fix it?

Comment: Not much of a recurrence, more of a linear interpolation.

Comment: For second array, do you expect a*2/3+c*1/3 and a*1/3+c*2/3?

Comment: does it need to be expandable to a list that has [a b c d]?

Comment: @Ben Yes! this problem is a function which can take up to `n` elements in an array.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I expect: `[a, a*2/3, a*1/3 + b*2/3, .. ]

Comment: @nneonneo Do you know how can I write a function to produce such linear interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy: takes a list as input, and produces a list as output.

```
public static <T extends Number> List<Double> expandThirds(List<T> input) {
    List<Double> output = new ArrayList<Double>();

    if(input.size() == 0)
        return output;

    output.add(input.get(0).doubleValue());

    for(int i=0; i<input.size()-1; i++) {
        double a = input.get(i).doubleValue();
        double b = input.get(i+1).doubleValue();
        output.add(a*2/3 + b/3);
        output.add(a*3 + b*2/3);
        output.add(b);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write like this:

```
double[] inputArray = new double[]{0.56,2.4,3.6};//pass you input array of size>1
List<Double> outList = new ArrayList<Double>();
//assuming minimum length of array = 2
for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length-1;i++){
    permute(inputArray[i], inputArray[i+1], outList);
}
System.out.println(outList);
```

where `generateRecurrance` is private custom method as below:

```
private void generateRecurrance(double a, double b, List<Double> outList) {
    outList.add(a);
    outList.add(a*1/3+b*2/3);
    outList.add(a*2/3+b*1/3);
    outList.add(b);
}
```

Comment: It's not a permutation; don't call it that.

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah. is `recurrance` fine as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @YogendraSingh The function is supposed to take in an array of `n` numbers

Comment: No, it's not a recurrence either (as I mentioned in a comment)...not really sure what I'd call what you wrote.

Comment: @philippe: I updated the answer to work on double array. Please feel free to change the type.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to handle the first case, and call it `mySequenceHelper`.  I won't write it here, but it should handle this case:

```
[a, b] --> [a*2/3+b/3, a*1/3+b*2/3, b];
```

Now write a function called `mySequence`, and have it pass each pair of numbers to `mySequenceHelper`, appending each set of results to a master list.  Here is a simple one in java:

```
public List<Float> mySequence(List<Float> inputs) {
    List<Float> toReturn = new LinkedList<Float>();

    // Add the first term manually:
    toReturn.add(inputs.get(0));

    // For each pair of values in inputs, add the appropriate 3 terms
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size() - 1; i++) {
        toReturn.addAll(mySequenceHelper(inputs.get(i), inputs.get(i+1)));
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: This would, unfortunately, repeat one of the endpoints. Perhaps you meant `[a, b] -> [a*2/3+b/3, a*1/3+b*2/3, b];`.